# How to prevent overlapping of int ranges

Tags: postgresql, gist

I have a table as follow :

```
CREATE TABLE appointments (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    start_mn INT NOT NULL,
    end_mn INT NOT NULL,
    EXCLUDE using gist((array[start_mn, end_mn]) WITH &&)
)
```

I want to prevent start_mn and end_mn overlapping between rows so I've added a gist exclusion :

```
EXCLUDE using gist((array[start_mn, end_mn]) WITH &&)
```

But inserting the two following do not trigger the exclusion:

```
INSERT INTO appointments(date, start_mn, end_mn) VALUES('2020-08-08', 100, 200);
INSERT INTO appointments(date, start_mn, end_mn) VALUES('2020-08-08', 90, 105);
```

How can I achieve this exclusion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to prevent an overlapping *range* you will have to use a [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) not an array.

I also assume that start and end should never overlap on the same day, so you need to include the `date` column in the exclusion constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE appointments 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    start_mn INT NOT NULL,
    end_mn INT NOT NULL,
    EXCLUDE using gist( int4range(start_mn, end_mn, '[]') WITH &&, "date" with =)
)
```

If `start_mn` and `end_mn` are supposed to be "time of the day", then those columns should be defined as `time`, not as integers.